# Is there a list of events for .on function? [Vanilla NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eventemitter

Currently working with NodeJS and trying to test out some basic (vanilla) backend things like sending different HTTP requests from my index.html file to my server.js file. Will be moving onto express shortly.

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on nodeJS 'events'. Like I have seen some events being used such as : 'end', 'data', etc.

*** I was wondering if there was a list of events that I could use because I can't find any lists at the moment online. NodeJS Docs. is really a hit or miss for me atm. ***

```
example:

if(request.method === 'POST && request.url === '/greeting') {
   let body = '';
   request.on('data', (chunkOfData) => {
   body += chunkOfData;
});

request.on('end', () => {
   'Bye!';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all depend on the what events are emitted by the underlying class.

In this case, you've got a `http.ClientRequest`, which is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest), and says that it extends `Stream`. Looking at [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams), an HTTP request on the server is a Readable stream, so has all the events listed under [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). These are, for posterity, `close`, `data`, `end`, `error`, `pause`, `readable`, `resume` in version 14.4.0. You can check the docs for each of them in the `stream.Readable` docs.